# Lua compilation link error

Tags: linker, compiler-errors, lua

When I try to compile a little lua program, I get these errors :

```
/usr/lib//liblua52.so: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/lib//liblua52.so: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/lib//liblua52.so: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/lib//liblua52.so: undefined reference to `dlclose'
```

Of course, I link with -ldl. I have lua5.2-dev installed on my ubuntu.
If you need any more infos ask me.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact compiler/linker command line that gives you this error?

Comment: g++ -o client Box.o ConnexionException.o GameData.o LuaManager.o main.o Parser.o ParsingException.o Player.o Socket.o -L/usr/lib/ -ldl -Llib/lib/ -Wl,--rpath=lib/lib -llua52 -Wl,--rpath=lib/lib -lSLB
/usr/lib//liblua52.so: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/lib//liblua52.so: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/lib//liblua52.so: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/lib//liblua52.so: undefined reference to `dlclose'

Comment: Put `-ldl` at the end of the link command line.

Comment: Already have it, not at the end but still.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I try to compile a little lua program, I get these errors

No. You get these errors when you *link* the program.

The fix is to add `-ldl` at the end of your link line.

Comment: Just to add  the background, let me add the link you put in a comment to my now deleted answer: http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to get this error is to have your PLAT variable set wrong in the Makefile. You need to set it in the top level Makefile and the src/Makefile.

The legal values show up about 10 lines down from the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure -ldl is exactly at the end of your link line as Employed Russian mentioned